# Would this be strong enough or just overkill?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email-server, network-attached-storage, web

I'm actually interested in building a web/mail server. I'll have database with thousands of users and multiple websites hosted on a LEMP Stack Server.

Hopefully I'll eventually have thousands of visitors daily on each website that I build (about 3 of them).

I wanted to use a **HP EliteDesk 800 G4 mini** as my web server with the following specs:

**CPU:** Intel Core i7-8700 / base 3.2 GHz/ Turbo 4.6GHz

**RAM:** 32GB DDR4-2666

**SSD Storage:** 1TB PCIe NVMe M.2 SSD

Do you think that this would perform well to handle a database of around 100,000 subscribers?

I was thinking that I could build a NAS Sever to handle all of the storage. Maybe about 20TB over time.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Also: Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they attract low quality, opinionated and spam answers, and the answers become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe the business problem you are working on, the research you have done, and the steps taken so far to solve it.

Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User, and questions about development, testing and development tools may be asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: According to who/what? I don't see anything wrong with this question. That's just your opinion.

Comment: @RomeoNinov Also, it clearly shows that I've already "described the business problem I'm working on", "the research I've done" (indirectly, of course, or else I wouldn't have had a starting point, correct?), "and the steps taken so far to solve it". I wouldn't have known anything about what I'm trying to achieve had I not already taken some steps in understanding the specifications and initiated steps to solving his problem here, correct? Who are you to dictate how perception should be perceived? Also, what is the point of a "forum" if it's not for "learning material"?

Comment: @Romeo Ninov And "Spam answers" can be given on ANY type of forum, if the "spammer" really wanted to do this.

Comment: Did you read **managing information technology systems in a business environment**? Your system is not in business environment, part or corporate system. Or at least you do not describe it as such.

Comment: @RomeoNinov Are you a moderator here? If you are, you can move this thread to the proper location. Either way, this forum site is about "servers", and my questions relates to "servers", correct?